# Generic QML delegate, but non-generic View attached properties?

Tags: qt, qml

A View attaches properties to a delegate. For a ListView, the delegate could access the `ListView.view.width` and `ListView.isCurrentItem` properties :

```
Rectangle {
  width: ListView.view.width
  height: 40

  color: ListView.isCurrentItem ? "gray" : "lightGray"

  Text {
    anchors.centerIn: parent       
    text: index
  }
}
```

By referring to the View by its type name, it seems like the Delegate loses its genericity.

What if I want to use the same delegate within a GridView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a Component from your delegate and set `property isCurrentItem` during its instantiation. In other words, create new qml file and name it e.g. "`Delegate.qml`" and add `property bool isCurrentItem`:

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Rectangle {
    property bool isCurrentItem: false
    width: parent.width
    height: 20
    color: isCurrentItem ? "gray" : "lightGray"
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: index
    }
}
```

than you can use it in ListView like:

```
ListView {
    model: 10
    width: 40
    height: 200
    delegate: Delegate {
        isCurrentItem: ListView.isCurrentItem
    }
}
```

and similarly in GridView:

```
GridView {
    model: 10
    width: 40
    height: 200
    delegate: Delegate {
        isCurrentItem: ListView.isCurrentItem
    }
}
```

You could do it same way to provide `width` of `ListView`/`GridView` to delegate, but in this case `parent.width` will also work the way you want.